# Bluetooth modules differences Android

Tags: bluetooth, xbee, android

i am not really well informed about the different types of Bluetooth modules, so i wanted to ask u what is the difference between these :

http://dx.com/p/csr-usb-2-0-bluetooth-v2-0-edr-adapter-module-green-187493

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8710 ( xbee module )

http://www.elecfreaks.com/store/bluetooth-shield-v10-p-233.html ( bt shield)

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/158

And why there is such big difference in their price ? I am thinking to connect a bth module with arduino + android, so which is simplest to use, cus i dont have much experience with android applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe price difference is because DX (and elecfreaks) is a cheap China shop, while Sparkfun is a US based operation. Quality differences, already imported, etc. Though DX has been around a while.

First, XBee isn't Bluetooth. Will not work with your phone's bluetooth connection.

The DX item, is a computer usb bluetooth module, without a case. While I did see some projects that used that type of bluetooth module, they involve playing usb host, not simple, and not the normal type of bluetooth module.

The Sparkfun Bluesmirf is a ultra high quality bluetooth serial module, high bit rate, and very high cost. They have cheaper ones available. By a third of the price.

The elecfreaks one is a common `HC-05` based bluetooth module, soldered onto an Arduino Board. Commonly used in arduino projects between an arduino board and iphones or android phones.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i admit that the question  was  a little bit silly, but i just dont get it ,because in our market there are only this one which have really good quality and so high price for me. I am looking for something which is half or 3/4 the quality and of course  for a smaller price . Especially i knew that this is a china shop and there the prices are lower, but so much lower i didnt expecte.

Comment: @ДимитърЦветков oh, well, I didn't mean to speak ill of DX, I buy from them, I just don't expect the thing to last for ten years. And the HC-05 module is available in many places (the hc-06 as well) and those are one of the most commonly used modules for arduino projects. Without the shield, the module is about 5~6 bucks, shipped to the US. There are also some boards for the module to arduino for 3 bucks (module is separate). Combined is around 7 or 8. All on ebay.

Comment: In fact i am from Europe.In my country the electronics arent much popular hobby and so there is 1-2 markets where i can buy things. If i try to buy from other places which arent participated in the european union,i need to pay extra cash and sometimes the order is confiscated.The DX is good cus if  i loose my order i will not throw so many funds to the wind ; ) . Anyway thanks for the information and hava a nice day.